# Why is it necessary to do a rebuild after adding a new member variable to a class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, build-process, rebuild

This morning, in Visual Studio 2005, I tried adding a new `private` member variable to a class and found that it was giving me all sorts of weird segmentation faults and the like.  When I went into debug mode, I found that my debugger didn't even see the new member variable, and thus it was giving me some strange behavior.

It required a "rebuild all" in order to get my program working again (and to get the debugger to see the new member variables I had made).  **Why was it necessary to rebuild all?  Why was just doing a regular build insufficient?**

I already solved the problem, but I feel like I understanding the build process better will help me in the future.  Let me know if there's any more information you need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was it a `public` or `private` variable?

Comment: It was `private` (just modified my question to reflect this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add or remove members of a class you change the memory layout of the object. If you don't recompile you are breaking the ODR rule, and the segmentation faults are just the effect of that.

As to why that happens, old code might be acquiring memory for the old size, and then passing that object (without the new member) to new code that will access beyond the end of the allocated memory to access the new variable. Note that the access specifier does not affect at all, if it is private it will probably be the class member functions the ones accessing the fields.

If you did not add the field to the end, but rather to the middle of the object, the same effect will be seen while accessing those fields that are laid out by the compiler in the higher memory addresses.

The fact that you needed to use the *rebuild all* feature is an indication that the dependencies of your project are not correctly configured, and you should fix that as soon as possible. Having the right dependencies will force the compiler into rebuilding when needed, and will mean less useless debugging hours.

Comment: If you add or remove members of a class, and the class is defined in a header, the build system should automatically recompile all of the files using that header.  Provided the build system works correctly (VS doesn't, but I doubt that he's in one of the cases where it fails) and you're using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious answer would be: "because Visual Studios is broken, and doesn't handle dependencies correctly".  In fact, however, I don't think you've given us enough information for me to be able to make that statement (and Visual Studios does get the simple cases right).

When you add members (`private` or `public`, it doesn't matter), especially data members, but also virtual functions, you change the physical layout of the class in memory.  All code which depends on that physical layout must be recompiled.  Normally, the build system takes care of this automatically, but a broken makefile, or a bug in the system, can easily mean that it doesn't.  (The correct answer isn't to invoke a rebuild/make clean, but to fix the problem with the build system.)

Comment: +1 I am inclined to think that it is more of a misconfiguration problem than a VS bug. But I wouldn't know, I don't use VS :)

Comment: @David I rather suspect as much as well.  I know that VS does have problems with managing dependencies, but only in special cases.  For everyday, simple applications, it does the job correctly.